# Inhomogeneous heat equation Neumann boundary conditions with f(x,t)=cos(2x).

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Consider the following inhomogeneous heat equation with Neumann boundary conditions.
$$
\begin{cases}
u_t-u_{xx}=\cos(2x)\\
u(x,0)=x \\
u_x(0,t)=u_x(\pi,t)=0
\end{cases}\text{ for }\:
\begin{align}
0<x<\pi,\\
0<t\quad
\end{align}$$
By separation of variables I arrive at the homogeneous solution
$$u_h(x,t)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty A_ne^{-n^2t}\cos(nx)$$
$$
A_n=
\begin{cases}
\pi /2 & n=0\\
-4/(\pi n^2)& \text{if $n$ is odd}\\
0& \text{if $n$ is even}
\end{cases}$$
On trying to find the inhomogeneous solution by applying Duhamel's principle i.e. using
$$u_p(x,t)=\int_0^t\sum_{i=0}^\infty B_n(s)\cos(nx)e^{-n^2(t-s)}ds$$
where
$$B_n(s)=2/\pi \int_0^\pi \cos(nx)\cos(2x) dx$$
I get
$$B_n(s)=0$$
What went wrong? Any assistance much appreciated.

Comment: $n$ isn't fixed, it can be any integer. Can you think of an integer where $B_n(s)$ is nonzero?

Comment: I can write cos(nx)cos(2x) as 1/2(cos((n+2)x)+cos((n-2)x)) which integrates to 
terms in sin which vanish for multiples of pi.
So I am struggling to find an integral n that produces anything other than zero.
I am clearly missing something?
A pi/2 would be nice

Comment: Thank you.  I missed the obvious!!!

Answer (score 1):

Using the Laplace transform

$$
{\cal L}\left(u_t-u_{xx}-\cos(2x)\right) = sU(s,x)-u(0,x)-U_{xx}(s,x)-\frac 1s\cos(2x)
$$

and now solving

$$
sU(s,x)-x-U_{xx}(s,x)-\frac 1s\cos(2x)=0,\ \ U_x(s,0)=U_x(s,\pi)
$$

we have

$$
U(s,x) = \frac{1}{s(s+4)}\left((s+4)x+\cos(2x)-(s(s+4))(e^{\sqrt s x}-e^{\sqrt s(s-x)})C(s)\right)
$$

now assuming that $U(s,x)$ remains limited as $x\to\infty$ we have $C(s) = 0$ and then

$$
U(s,x) = \frac xs+\frac{\cos(2x)}{s(s+4)}
$$

with inverse

$$
u(t,x) = \frac 14\left(1-e^{-4 t}\right) \cos (2 x)+x
$$